How to calculate the next tensor(i+1) on GPU while evaluating the tensor i?
I'm doing a feature calculating and feature evaluating task in a for loop. There are about a thousand features in total. The evaluating function costs about the same time as the calculating function. The calculating is on the GPU but the evaluating is on the GPU, so I think it's possible to calculate the next feature(i+1) and evaluate the feature(i) simutsimultaneously. It will utilize the GPU more sufficient and make the whole process quicker. But I find it difficult to implement using the concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor. It seems that it will always calculate all the data in the loop and then start evaluating, even if I used the as_completed().
with ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
    futures_a = []; futures_b = []
    
    with tqdm(total=2) as progress:
        for i in range(len(candidate_features)):
            future = executor.submit(calc_feature_data, candidate_features[i], data['feature'])
            futures_a.append(future)
            future.add_done_callback(lambda p: progress.update())

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_a):
            if future.done():
                print("done")
                feature = future.result()
                future_b = executor.submit(eval_feature, feature)
                futures_b.append(future_b)

         concurrent.futures.wait(futures_B)


